Decomposition of measures orthogonal to the algebra $R(K_1 \times \ldots \times K_n)$ - Can it be done via projection-preserving products of bands?
See "Measures orthogonal to tensor products of function algebras" by Marek Kosiek. Here, it is described for the two-dimensional case. It uses another, more general, approach to OB Bekken's 1974 paper "Rational Approximation on Product Sets" by using projection-preserving (tensor) products of bands of measures.
After applying Lemma II 7.4 from "Uniform algebras" by Gamelin to Theorem 2.6, we obtain Bekken's decomposition of measures orthogonal to the algebra $R(K_1 \times K_2)$, where $K_i$ is a compact subset of the complex plane. See Theorem 3.1 in Kosiek's paper.
Now, the question which is very interesting and crucial for my PhD advisor and me, is whether one can generalize this to the $n$-dimensional case.
As far as I understand, what Kosiek is doing here, is taking equation (2.8), which is:
$$M(X_1 \times X_2) = \widetilde{\pi_i^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_i)} + \widetilde{\pi_i^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_i^s)}$$
where $\mathcal{M}_i$ is a band in $M(X_i)$ and $\mathcal{M}_i^s$ is the band singular to $\mathcal{M}_i$. What $\widetilde{\pi_i^{-1} (\cdot)}$ is, is explained in this paper - it's not too important for this question now.
Now, we can formulate (2.8) once for $\mathcal{M}_1 \in M(X_1)$ and  $\mathcal{M}_2 \in M(X_2)$. Obviously, $M(X_1 \times X_2) \cap M(X_1 \times X_2) = M(X_1 \times X_2)$, but wouldn't
$$ \left( \widetilde{\pi_1^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_1)} + \widetilde{\pi_1^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_1^s)} \right) \cap \left( \widetilde{\pi_2^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_2)} + \widetilde{\pi_2^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_2^s)} \right)$$
give us Theorem 2.6?
And if so, would it be sufficient to take e.g.
$$ \left( \widetilde{\pi_1^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_1)} + \widetilde{\pi_1^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_1^s)} \right) \cap \left( \widetilde{\pi_2^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_2)} + \widetilde{\pi_2^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_2^s)} \right) \cap \left( \widetilde{\pi_3^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_3)} + \widetilde{\pi_3^{-1} (\mathcal{M}_3^s)} \right)$$
to obtain the $3$-dimensional case?
What makes me wonder, is that in this case, wouldn't we also obtain such a decomposition, that some measures in that decomposition would be supported on a Cartesian product of two null-sets and one $X_i$? But wouldn't that be contradictory to Bekken's iterative method (where we would not obtain measures supported on Cartesian products consisting of more than one null-set)?
